# Creating a module that delegates the usage of two other modules with the same methods (but different implementations)

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is this possible?

Specifically

```
module A
  def foo
    puts "a"
  end
end

module B
  def foo
    puts "b"
  end
end

module C
  def foo
   if self.name=='Frank'
    #send to A.foo
   elsif self.name=='Bob'
    #send to B.foo
   end
  end
end

class Person
  include C
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
   self.name=name
  end
end

f=Person.new('frank').foo # => "a"
f.name="Bob"
f.foo # => "b"
```

Also, assume that module A and B are third-party and cannot be modified.

In other words, I want to include both A and B into the Person class, but dynamically choose which method is used based on the state of a class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

**Code**

```
module A
  def foo
    puts "a"
  end
end

module B
  def foo
    puts "b"
  end
end

module C
  include A
  alias :fooA :foo
  include B
  alias :fooB :foo 
  def foo
    if self.name =='Frank'
      fooA
    elsif self.name == 'Bob'
      fooB
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include C
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
   self.name=name
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
f=Person.new('Frank')
f.foo        # => "a"
f.name="Bob"
f.foo        # => "b"
```

**Explanation**

- When the code is parsed, `module A` is included in `module C`
- The method `:foo` (from `module A`) is assigned an alias, `:fooA`, so so `module C` now contains methods `:fooA` and `foo`
- `module B` is included in `module C`
- The method `:foo` from `module B` overwrites `:foo`
- The method `:foo` (from `module B`) is assigned an alias, `:fooB`, so `module C` now contains `:fooA`, `fooB` and `foo` (from `module B`)
- The method `foo` is created using `def`, overwriting `foo` from `module B`
- When `class Person` includes `module C`, it mixes in the three instance methods, `:fooA`, `:fooB` and `:foo`

Comment: This looks good, but give me a chance to take a deeper look into (I'm about to leave for the weekend).